# Shock in the Inviscid Burgers Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, characteristics

I'm trying to implement the Finite-Volume method using local Lax-Friedrichs flux function. I found an example to the Riemann-problem, here is the solution plot:
[image]

So from characteristics $$u=\begin{cases}
1, x<\frac{1}{2}t \\
0, x>\frac{1}{2}t
\end{cases}$$
How can we see from the plot where the shock is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a numerical way of finding the shock, you could take your array $u[i,j]$ and consider the partial derivative in the x-direction: 
 `dudx = diff(u) / dx`

And then if you contour plot dudx, you should get an image where the shock shows up as yellow. This should be along the line $t = 2x$, which you can see in your plot above.

Comment: I tried to follow your advice, and I got smth like this: https://imgur.com/FLzCyMo, seems a little bit awkward, I picked the number of nodes $x$ to be $100$ on $[-3,3], dt = 0.01$
Can you show what I should get?

Comment: That’s more or less what you should get, with the exception of the loop that juts our from the origin to the left.