# A picture of a shock wave for a nxn system of PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, fluid-dynamics, hyperbolic-equations

Let's start from the concrete 2x2 system. In the Chapter 5 of the *"Front tracking for hyperbolic conservation laws" - Holden, Risebro, 2011*, we could find *a shallow water system*:

$$h_t+q_x=0,$$
$$q_t+(\frac{q^2}{h}+\frac{h^2}{2})_x=0,$$

with Riemann initial data:

$$
(h,q)(x,0)= \begin{cases}
(h_l,q_l), x<0 \\[2ex]
(h_r,q_r), x> 0,
\end{cases}
$$

Here $h_l , h_r, u_l, u_r$ are constants in $\mathbb{R}$ and $h \in  \mathbb{R}$, $q \in  \mathbb{R}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $t \in [0,T]$.

One of the solutions of this problem is given with a shock wave:

$$(1) \hspace{1cm}
(h,q)(x,t)= \begin{cases}
(h_l,q_l), x< s t \\[2ex]
(h_r,q_r), x> s t,
\end{cases}
$$

where $s$ is the speed of the discontinuity.

**My question is: how do we imagine $(1)$ in the 3D plain?** Let me explain.

*A conservation law* in the area of PDEs is given with:

$$(2) \hspace{1cm} u_t+f(u)_x=0,$$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $t \in [0,T]$, $u=u(x,t)=(u_1,u_2,...,u_n)$, $f=f(u)=(f_1,f_2,...,f_n)$. If $n=1$, we talk about scalar conservation law. If $n>1$, we talk about system of nxn conservation laws. A shallow water system represents 2x2 system of conservation laws.

In $(2)$ when $n=1$, shock wave is given with:

$$(3) \hspace{1cm}
u(x,t)= \begin{cases}
u_l, x<st \\[2ex]
u_r, x>st.
\end{cases}
$$

On the picture in "$x-t-u$" plane and for the positive speed $s$, shock wave given with $(3)$ would look like this:

[image: shock wave solution]

Here by "variable" we mean "u".

**But what happens in the case $n>1$? How do we imagine shock waves then?** Of course in the case of $n>1$, $(3)$ would look the same, it would just have $n$ components of $u_l$ and $u_r$ (for example in $(1)$ $u_l=(h_l,q_l)$, $u_r=(h_r,q_r)$ - so they have two components each).

**My thoughts:**

- In order to picture that we would need some "(n+2)D plane $x-t-u_1-...-u_n$". So that is not possible to imagine that way. A professor of mine have told me that in 3D we imagine all of the $n$ components on the same picture i.e. all in the "$x-t-u$" plane but that looks confusing even for the $n=2$.
- OR maybe we could imagine it in $n$ planes "$x-t-u_1,...., x-t-u_n$" (but the problem with this is that $(3)$ as whole is a shock wave solution, and we do not think of every component as a shock waves).
- OR maybe we could use some other type of a 3D plane instead of "$x-t-u$"?

At first I was thinking that answer to this questions was obvious but now I am not so sure. Help with this would be great (and help with pictures would be amazing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wave speeds will be the same for all the conserved variables. The only thing that will change from one variable to another are the left and right constant states (two of which are known from the initial condition). Indeed, it does not seem reasonable to combine several conserved variables on a single $x$-$t$-variable 3D plot, but one can still represent at most one variable on one 3D plot. Alternatively, some 2D plots could be produced:

One may plot the conserved variables or normalized conserved variables at fixed time $t$ with respect to the space variable $x$: (from P.L. Roe, *J. Comput. Phys.* **43**, 1981)

[image: Roe]

Of course one could do the opposite by representing the conserved variables w.r.t. $t$ for a fixed position $x$, but it is less common in fluid dynamics.

Another classical representation corresponds to your 3D representation viewed from above. It is a plot of the wave location in the $x$-$t$ plane, such as (from K.V. Karelsky, A.S. Petrosyan, *Fluid Dyn. Res.* **38**, 2006)

[image: plane]

This graph displays the wave trajectories in $x$-$t$ coordinates. For shock waves, this may be interpreted as a map of the gradient's norm $\| h_x + q_x \|$, which can be evaluated numerically (see e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3164805/418542) where the scalar case is presented).

Comment: Harry49, thank you for the answer with pictures :). Yes, the speed is the same for every component of a shock wave, and yes, the only difference is the left and right constant value for every component. Combination of a several variables on a one 3D plot is messy and I would like to avoid it (One component in "x-t-u" plane is ok but it doesn't give the real picture by my professor). On your first plot you fixed variable t, your horizontal axis is x, and on the vertical are "shock wave components". So this is 2D plot of "all the variables on one picture". It looks better than 3D picture.

Comment: I have an additional questions. Could you on your 2D picture fix x outside, put your horizontal axis to be t, and all the components of a shock wave on the vertical axis? So you would fix a point in space and draw how the variables change in time. I do stochastic processes, and that maybe could have some sense. Also, on your second picture, you basicaly plot "all the variables on one picture" and then look on it from above? Does this picture have 5 components and every one of them is given as a shock wave i.e. like $(3)$ in my question or it represent something else? Thanks for the help again.

Comment: Fixing x outside isn't common in fluid dynamics but it maybe has some sense in the stochastic processes if we want to observe trajectories of the process. I made mistake in my second comment. Because the speed is the same for every component, and the only thing that is different are the values of the left and right constant states for every variable, ** if I look at that from above (such as the case in your second picture) I would have just one line?** On your picture, you have 5 shock waves for every component (my picture has one shock wave for every component - so I have one line then)?

Comment: Just two more things. When we plot "component by component" in 3D for a nxn system, for example in "$x-t-u_1$" plane, do we fix outside $u_2,u_3,...,U_n$ or not? I think they are not fixed but I am not sure. And the second thing: for 2x2 systems we use "phase plane" i.e. 2D plane "$u_1 - u_2$". Is there any sense in using 3D planes "$x-u_1 - u_2$" or "$t-u_1 - u_2$"? (Probably not). And huge thanks for the edit.

Comment: @Mark Yes, you will obtain one line in your case. You are right: When plotting one variable in $x$-$t$-variable coordinates, the other variables are not necessarily constant. They are just absent from the graph. The representation in the $u_1$-$u_2$ phase plane of conserved variables is indeed useful, as is the representation in the plane of Riemann invariants (when such invariants exist). For the coordinates $x$-$u_1$-$u_2$ and so on, I don't see any use.

Comment: Harry49, thank you for all your effort. It clarified me more then a few things. Drawing a picture is very useful in fluid dynamics. But we usually do that for the equtions and not the systems. So your answer and the comment help a lot.